# Having problem building and running vscode source code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having the same problem as [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203619) VSCode issue is having. It's about MSB8040 "Missing spectre mitigated libraries on Windows".

I have provided my information on the issue, so if you could help with this issue please help on that issue.

What I expect from this SO question is whether there is a way to build and run VSCode without using node-gyp and this security invulnerability taken into account.

From my understanding, you want to use node-gyp to compile it to native level or something to run it faster, and the said 'spectre mitigation' is a security invulnerability.

Sure, it's a great practice to have everything run faster and securely, but the problem is I can't even get started with trying out this VSCode's source code.

Basically, it's all fast and secure and nice if what the instruction on How to contribute [page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute) works, but even after so many googling and trying to fix this myself, I see myself resorting to "I just want to have it up and running on my computer".

I would love to post this on VSCode issues but it seems to only accept feature requests, bug and security reports, and told me to ask questions here. Thank you in advance